Wine: application settings not saved upon (unclean) exit
First of all apologies for posting this actual Wine problem here. I tried the WineHQ forum already but unfortunately, no one was able to help me there. Maybe I'm more lucky here.
I have a problem running Wine 9.0 and Windows app settings. Whenever an app exits "unclean" (e.g. I just reboot my PC) without closing the Windows app before, all settings will just be lost. I observe this behavior ever since using Wine - it's not specific to version 9.0.
As an example, when running Notepad++ under Wine, I enable auto word wrap in its settings. This works and is also restored properly when I close Notepad++ explicitly before a reboot. When I just reboot my PC without closing Notepad++ before, all settings I made will just be lost. And the settings of the last "clean" exit will be restored when I open Notepad++ next time. Can this be prevented somehow, e.g. by saving the state of a running Windows app periodically somehow? Or is there a trick that I can tell Linux (Ubuntu 20.04 in my case) to close any running Wine app "cleanly" rather than killing it forcibly, e.g. before a reboot?
Notepad++ is just one example. It happens for other Windows apps, too.
Any help is greatly appreciated. Many thanks in advance.

After fiddling around with my session manager (gdm3's PostSession script), I ended up creating a .desktop file and adding it to my dash:
$ cat ~/.local/share/applications/clean-shutdown.desktop 
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Clean shutdown
Exec=sh -c "gnome-session-quit --power-off && wmctrl -l | cut -d ' ' -f1 | xargs -rL1 wmctrl -ic"
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Icon=system-shutdown
Comment=Closes all open windows cleanly through wmctrl before shutdown (saves Wine app settings properly)

Not the most elegant solution, but does the trick for now.
The only minor downside is that the wmctrl command is always executed, even if I don't confirm the shutdown dialog. I did not find out how to overcome this.
